# Избавиться от проблем раннего уничтожения главного объекта

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Хочу избавиться от проблем раннего уничтожения главного объекта, от которого создаются другие объекты (так же они критично зависят от него), и от того что нельзя уничтожить главный объект пока на него ссылаются другие объекты.

Попробовал использовать статический `Dictionary` который содержал бы в себе все главные объекты, и ссылки на потомки. Но! Тут возникает проблема. Нельзя изменять коллекцию в цикле. Т.е. вызывается уничтожение главного объекта, и он тут же начинает чистить за собой весь мусор что остается в памяти (связанные с ним ссылки на объекты).

Снова и снова, что бы я не пытался предпринять, ничего хорошего кроме как исключений об изменении коллекции и невозможности дальнейшего перечисления я так и не добился. Есть ли какие-то идеи как такое реализовать, и может ли в моем случае помочь двусвязный список `LinkedList`?

Принцип работы главного класса:

```
      +----------------------+
      |      RootObject      |
      +----------------------+
     /                        \
    /                          \
+-----------+             +----------------+
| ChildClass|  ---------> | SomeChildClass |
+-----------+             +----------------+
```

Без `RootObject` не может существовать ни `ChildClass` ни `SomeChildClass`, при этом необходимо учесть что `SomeChildClass` может быть создан не только из главного объекта, но еще и из `ChildClass`, при этом `ChildClass` не может быть создан без `RootObject`, а `RootObject` не может быть уничтожен, пока есть хоть один живой экземпляр `ShildClass` или `SomeChildClass`, даже в том случае если `SomeChildClass` был создан из `ChildClass`, он так же ссылается на `RootObject`

Comment: Сейчас добавлю объяснение ситуации зависимостей картинкой, для более понятного объяснения ситуации.

Comment: Память освобождается автоматически сборщиком мусора. Ты что–то не то делаешь.

Comment: @Qwertiy: было бы так, если в классе не содержались бы неуправляемые объекты, порядок уничтожение которых критичен.

Comment: Используй `IDisposable`?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Да, я его и использую. Но! Если не будет выполнено уничтожение дочерних классов, по какой бы то ни было причине, `RootObject` не сможет быть уничтожен. Это необходимо учесть при уничтожении `RootObject`'a.

Comment: У вас проблема удалить из коллекции?

Comment: @nick_n_a: Частично да, при изменении коллекции в цикле, дальнейшее перечисление становится невозможным.

Comment: Так... вычислили `a`, а за циклом сделали `Remove(a)`. Если надо много удалить, создать список, наполнить список первым циклом, а потом цикло по списку -> Remove. Всё.

Comment: `for` в обратную сторону.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте подсчет ссылок: подсчитывайте сколько SomeChildClass ссылается на RootObject и уничтожайте последний только когда счетчик достиг 0.

Чтобы не словить проблем с гонками - можно унаследовать оба класса от SafeHandle и использовать `DangerousAddRef()/DangerousRelease()`.